# Cant locate kernel modules that I want to disable

Tags: linux-kernel

So I was installing [KISS Linux](https://kisslinux.org/install) (a source-based distrobution similar to Gentoo) and while compiling my kernel, I noticed some modules that I didn't remember enabling (I wanted to install without an initramfs so I didn't enable any modules). I can't find these options in the ncurses menu (to directly build them into the kernel).

These are the modules I don't want:

```
CC [M]  net/netfilter/nf_log_common.o
CC [M]  net/ipv6/netfilter/nf_log_ipv6.o
CC [M]  net/netfilter/xt_addrtype.o
CC [M]  net/netfilter/xt_MASQUERADE.o
CC [M]  net/netfilter/xt_LOG.o
CC [M]  net/netfilter/xt_nat.o
CC [M]  net/netfilter/xt_mark.o
CC [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_log_arp.o
CC [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_log_ipv4.o
CC [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.o
```

Comment: these aren't kernel modules (.ko), but intermediate build objects (.o). There's nothing to disable here – these get linked together to form your kernel.

Comment: @MarcusMüller check out the contents of `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/netfilter` on your system... The logs are misleading, these are modules (`CC [M]` is the giveaway).

Answer (score 1):

To determine which configuration options to disable, look for the names of the object files you don’t want in the corresponding Makefile; for example:

```
$ grep xt_LOG.o net/netfilter/Makefile
obj-$(CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG) += xt_LOG.o
```

This means you need to disable `NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG`.

Apply the same approach for all the other object files.